# Proving that: $ \sum_{j=1}^{\log_2m}m/2^j \geq m-1 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Proving that:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\log_2m}m/2^j \geq m-1
$$

I tried to use geometric serie and use the formula:

$$
S = a_1 \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}
$$

Changed to:

$$
m\sum_{j=1}^{\log_2m}1/2^j 
$$

For

$$
a_1 = 1/2, q = 1/2, n = \log_2m
$$

Getting:

$$
m\sum_{j=1}^{\log_2m}1/2^j  = m(1-0.5^{\log_2m})
$$

But I don't see how it satisfies:

$$
m(1-0.5^{\log_2m}) \geq m-1
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $m(1-0.5^{log_2 m}) = m-1$. Since $0.5^{log_2 m}=2^{-log_2 m}=1/m$.

Comment: If we sum from $j = 1$ to $log_2m$ why $n = log_2m - 1$ and not $log_2m$? For example if we sum from $i = 1$ to $i = 2$ the number of elements in the sum is $2$ and not $1$

Comment: Sorry. You’re right. The value n should be $log_2m$. ^^